# SQL Sum and Count Separated by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a script that query's a table and counts all rows that have a status of 10 and separates the total count by month. Something is
not right considering I have two Decembers in my results.

In November, there is only one date in it meaning two rows have a status of 10 and are under the same date (11-04). December has 252 rows on the same date (12-04) and 1 row with a 12-05 date .

How to query and separate a count and date by months?

Any help is most appreciated.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), Datename(month, datecomplete)) AS Month, 
       Count(*)                                        AS Val 
FROM   nwds 
WHERE  status = 10 
GROUP  BY Datediff(month, 0, datecomplete), 
          datecomplete
```

My Results

```
Nov 2
Dec 252
Dec 1
```

Desired Results

```
Nov 2
Dec 253
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(M, datecomplete), 3) AS Month, 
       Count(*)                           AS Val 
FROM   nwds 
WHERE  status = 10 
GROUP  BY LEFT(DATENAME(M, datecomplete), 3)
```

If you have ever get data for different years, you can add the year to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(M, datecomplete), 3) AS Month, 
       YEAR(datecomplete)                 AS Year,
       Count(*)                           AS Val 
FROM   nwds 
WHERE  status = 10 
GROUP  BY LEFT(DATENAME(M, datecomplete), 3), YEAR(datecomplete)
```

Answer (score 1):

`datecomplete` should be excluded from `group by`, or the results would be grouped by day. Grouping needs to be on `month` and `year` part of datecomplete column.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(3), Datename(month, datecomplete)) AS Month, 
count(*)  AS Val 
FROM   nwds 
WHERE  status = 10 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(CHAR(3), Datename(month, datecomplete)) ,
datepart(yyyy, datecomplete)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select CONVERT(char(3),DATENAME(MONTH,datecomplete)) as [month],
       count(*)                                      as val
from nwds
WHERE  status = 10 
group by CONVERT(char(3),DATENAME(MONTH,datecomplete))
```